# How can I modify an element of an array?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a simple array like this one:

```
myArray = {1, 2, 17}
```

At some point I want that 2 to be a 4. How can I change it?

Comment: you can use Replace or ReplacePart...

Comment: `myArray[[2]] = 4;`.

Comment: `myNewArray = MapAt[4 &, myArray, 2]`